# How to exclude rows from a text file for loop

Tags: loops, unix, foreach, csh

I have a textfile (file1.txt) with multiple lines of data.
This textfile I'm using to copy data from a directory A to another B. My script looks if an expression is included in a filename of a file stored in A.
In the directory A I grep another textfile (file2.txt) to get information (rows like `[bla][0-9][0-9][bla][0-9][0-9]`) that I want to exclude in my script.

```
set x = `grep '[bla][0-9][0-9][bla][0-9][0-9]' file1.txt`

foreach i ( $x )
    cp A/*$i* B/.
end
```

For example rows in file1.txt:

```
bla11bla11
bla12bla12
bla13bla13
bla14bla14
bla15bla15
```

and grep result from file2.txt that has to be excluded for the loop

```
bla11bla11
bla12bla12
```

My script should finally only use the following lines

```
bla13bla13
bla14bla14
bla15bla15
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Where did you get that syntax from?

Comment: That would appear to be `csh` syntax (or something close to it).

Comment: Would it be a good idea to change the tags? Stefan, can you clarify which shell you are working in?

Comment: It is a C-shell script

Comment: Make the first line be `/bin/csh -vx` to see what is being executed and when. This will show you what values are being used for each variable as each line of code is executed. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A simple nested loop does it completely in csh:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set f = `grep 'bla[0-9][0-9]bla[0-9][0-9]' file1.txt`
set x = `grep 'bla[0-9][0-9]bla[0-9][0-9]' file2.txt`

echo "Files: $f"
echo "To be excluded from Files: $x"

set r = ( )
foreach i ( $f )
  set skip = 0
  foreach j ( $x )
    if ("$i" == "$j") then
      set skip = 1
      break
    endif
  end
  if ($skip == 0) set r = ($r $i)
end

echo "Result: $r"
```

The output when run on your above example files:

```
Files: bla11bla11 bla12bla12 bla13bla13 bla14bla14 bla15bla15
To be excluded from Files: bla11bla11 bla12bla12
Result: bla13bla13 bla14bla14 bla15bla15
```